# My profile views went from 5 to 1?

Tags: support, profile-page, views

From yesterday to today, when it went past midnight my profile views went from 5 to 1?

There also might be an error because when I hit 15 rep I got notifications in my recent achievements for being able to chat and a few other things but when I got marked -2 unfortunately for a newbie Stackoverflow question I had, someone marked my question as bad or whatever it is and marked me down 2 but the notifications didn't remove themselves showing my new achievements which had me very confused as I tried to use the chat feature. About 10 minutes later I understood what happened, but in my opinion, the notification area should reflect when you lose points and be dynamic in that regard.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't switch from your main account to your meta account? Your main account still has 5 profile views right now, your meta account has 1.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I did. On Meta I do have 1 profile view and on Stackoverflow I have 5 profile views. Since the rep was the same I thought profile views would have stayed the same too. Thanks for the clarification guys.

How about the second part of my question about my privileges being granted but then being removed after I got a down vote, but it still was showing in my Recent Achievements,  Badges and Privileges Notification area drop down as I still had achieved those new privileges but I in fact could not chat for instance, again, due to the down vote.

Comment: You should really keep your questions to one issue at a time though. I've updated my answer, but your achievement box only shows actual achievements (things gained), not things lost.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking at your [Meta account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4044817/tommydevs); your [*main account*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4044817/tommydevs) has 5 profile views:

[image: profile shot]

Note the *meta user* link on there; if you see *main user* instead, click on it to switch.

In the meantime, by posting about your profile, your Meta account now has 5 profile views too.

The achievement box will never show loss of reputation; only things you gain are shown. So when you lose points, lose a privilege or lose a tag badge, that's not considered an 'achievement' and it is not shown. This is by design.

Answer (score 4):

You are not notified when you lose a privilege.

You are not notified when you regain that privilege.

This is by design - otherwise your inbox would potentially become very noisy around the time you cross a privilege threshold.

Comment: Oh ok. I just thought it'd be easy programming to say if user rep < $chatrep (remove notification)? Or something along those lines. (I'm still learning back-end as I'm just a HTML/CSS designer from comps handed to me by the designers so forgive me if that back-end terminology doesn't make sense all the way, but ya get what I mean I hope. :) I as well think it'd be annoying to receive another notification to say you lost it but I thought it'd be helpful to at least remove it so users don't get confused why the Control Panel tells them one thing yet they're not able to use that functionality. :)

Comment: @tommydevs - it probably would be easy programming to do the notification, but it was decided not to for other reasons.

Comment: Roger that. @ChrisF are you a MOD. J/C. Is that what the diamond means?

Comment: Yes, I'm a mod. Not an employee (who are also, confusingly, marked with diamonds).

Comment: @ChrisF: Perhaps employees should have their diamonds in another color. Like the suggestion for hollow diamonds for ex-mods/ex-employees...